# Running emacs (gtk) through X410 from WSL Docker - program exits when idle

Tags: emacs, docker, x-windows, wsl2

I've started trying to use Docker for my daily development environment to make it easy (in principle) to work from any arbitrary machine without a lot of setup fuss. My environment is based on Emacs+Slime running with a custom Common Lisp image (although I don't think the Slime/Common Lisp part matters -- I'm pretty sure a plain Emacs would have the same problem described below).

Current host environment is Windows10/WSL2 with Docker running in the WSL2. I launch my container from a Windows Terminal WSL Ubuntu shell with something like the following:

```
docker run -d -it -rm -e DISPLAY="${DISPLAY}" <my-container-name> <command-within-container-to-launch-emacs>
```

where I have arranged for ${DISPLAY} to be the IP address of my Windows host, using the following in my WSL Ubuntu `.profile` to set it upon login:

```
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0.0
```

This `docker run` command happily launches my Emacs window on my Windows10 desktop through the X410 XWindow client I have installed (which is set to "Allow Public Access").

If I'm actively using the system, interacting with the emacs window, it works flawlessly for an indefinite amount of time.

The problem arises if the system is left idle for even a short amount of time (I don't think the host machine even has to go to sleep -- just leaving the emacs window idle for a few minutes will exhibit the problem). The problem is that the emacs window (and with it, the entire docker container) simply exit silently.

Could someone guide me in what would be some steps for troubleshooting this silent exiting of the container? E.g. would there be a logfile somewhere I should be looking at?

As this only seems to happen with X Window applications, perhaps this is a question for the X Window or X410 community rather than a docker question? If so please feel free to bump me to there.

Or perhaps it's an emacs (gtk) specific issue and I need to reach out to that community?

Or perhaps it's a WSL2 issue? (although an emacs (gtk) launched directly from the WSL2 Ubuntu windows terminal, also displayed through X410, stays up indefinitely even across sleeps & wakes of the machine (LG Gram laptop).

But I haven't had this issue with emacs-gtk in any other environment other than with docker, so I thought to ask here first .

Any guidance appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED!

I have had the same problem as you and just recently found a viable solution for me. I don't think it has anything to do with Emacs iteself.

I had tried running graphical linux apps in Windows with both Vcxsrv and X410 when I noticed that x410 had a new release 3.1.0 which support **vsock**. I think this is the key here since there seem to be some issues in ip-traffic between host Windows and WSL2.
*(Normally that is not visible but becomes so with an X-server using tcp-ip-address for communication)*

After downloading X410 latest version and setting up vsock all my problems was gone. Their solution for vsock might work for vcxsrv also but I have not tried that since x410 provides better details in the graphics and I prefer that.

> #### Why vsock ?
>
> Using vsock brings the independency from TCP and IP addresses that was a problem for me.
> With this solution I can switch network without loosing any linux app GUI. Happy days!

### This is what I did:

#### Download X410 version 3.1.0 for windows and install - https://x410.dev/#download

1. Start_ X410: `/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Choung\ Networks/X410/X410.exe &`

#### Use option VSOCK OPTION 2 Modify XCB - https://x410.dev/cookbook/transparently-adding-native-support-for-vsock-in-x11-apps

1. Download pre-built library - https://gitlab.com/vsockfy/libxcb-1.14-vsock/-/releases/v1.14-vsock
2. Rename old libxcb.so: `sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.backup.so.1.1.0`
3. Copy the downloaded file into place (move to your folder beforehand): `sudo cp libxcb.se.1.1.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0`
4. Verify functionality: `export DISPLAY=vsock/:0; xset q`   (Should respond with 'Keyboard Control:......' if successful)

#### Add aliases and functions to your .bashrc or similar:

1. Add alias to launch X410

```
alias xlaunch='/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Choung\ Networks/X410/X410.exe &'
```

3. Add function:

```
function x_display {
  export DISPLAY="vsock/:0"
  export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1
  export GDK_SCALE=1
  if ! timeout 1s xset q &>/dev/null; then
    taskkill.exe /IM X410.exe &> /dev/null && echo "Running X was killed!"
    echo "Starting X..."
    xlaunch
    sleep 2
  fi
  echo "X for WSL instantiated on $DISPLAY"
}
```

4. Add alias to launch intellij (my reason for this endevour):

```
alias intellij='x_display; /opt/idea/bin/idea.sh &> /dev/null &'
```

5. Save your .bashrc
6. Source your changed .bashrc: source ~/.bashrc
7. Start Intellij: intellij